# Recursive functions scala

Tags: scala

```
def r(x: Int, y: Int): Int =

  if (x==y) x

  else if (x>y) r(x-y, y)

  else r(x, y-x)
```

r(22, 18)

Could someone guide me through the logic to why this returns 4, I can't get my head around it.

Comment: Have you tried to write stack of calls with results of evaluation?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. It returns 2, just like it should.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't return 4. It returns 2. It's easiest to look at each individual recursive call to `r`:

When you call `r(22, 18)` the `x>y` branch is hit so the next call is `r(22-18, 18)` or `r(4, 18)`.

When `r(4, 18)` is called you hit the `else` branch so the next call is `r(4, 18-4)` or `r(4, 14)`.

The next few will hit the `else` branch producing the following calls:

```
r(4, 14)
r(4, 10)
r(4, 6)
r(4, 2)
```

Now with `r(4, 2)` we hit the `x>y` branch again which produces the call `r(4-2, 2)` or `r(2, 2)`.

`r(2, 2)` satisfies our base case branch of `x==y` so we simply return `x` (2) at that point.

To test with different examples you can modify the function slightly to print each call:

```
scala> def r(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
     |   println(s"r($x, $y)")
     |   if (x == y) x
     |   else if (x > y) r(x-y, y)
     |   else r(x, y-x)
     | }
r: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

scala> r(22, 18)
r(22, 18)
r(4, 18)
r(4, 14)
r(4, 10)
r(4, 6)
r(4, 2)
r(2, 2)
res1: Int = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @gregghz that it returns **2** rather than **4** and you can clearly see it [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/5J4PGtelQv2tSnVQHvhUHA). But I think the proper point of view as to why it returns **2** is that because it was designed to do so. This is an implementation of one if the oldest know algorithms - [the Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) which is designed to calculate [GCD aka Greatest Common Divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor). And obviously `gcd(22,18)  = 2`